# Moxy bootstrapping from XSD vs OXM.xml?

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, moxy

In the blog http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/04/moxys-object-graphs-dynamic-jaxb.html

*There is an oxm.xml file, which is an external mapping document. is there any tool which can generate it from XSD?*

We have used Moxy framework and implemented bootstrapping from XSD like in the link

http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/moxy/dynamic_jaxb003.htm

This has increased the complexity of algorithm and program is becoming tightly coupled?

Can you please suggest as to how to proceed?

Comment: Basically difference in createContextFromXSD vs createContextFromOXM in DynamicJAXBContext class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOXy does not currently contain a way to generate an external mapping document (oxm.xml) from an XML schema file.

You can use the external metadata file to customize the metadata of a dynamic model bootstrapped from an XML schema, but as you say it does require that you know details about the model.  What I find helps is to generate a real static model to use as a guide.

Comment: With your experience which is recommended?  I used createContextFromXSD and ended up with some complex code! We had a constraint to keep everything in XSD